# Excel - add all score related to a name

Tags: excel, loops, excel-formula

I have an Excel document where in column A actions are listed, in column B the name of the person who did it and in the column C the score related to that action.

Is it possible to make a formula that adds all the scores of a person into one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Sumif.

=SUMIF(A,B,C)

- A = your table
- B = the name of the person/cell of the name of the person
- C = Entire column C

Comment: This looks interesting I'll try it out.